# Export(backup) website\app using msdeploy api c#

Tags: c#, msdeploy

How to export (backup) an website/app using msdeploy api c#?

I know how to synchronize my website/app.

```
private void AppSynchronization(DeploymentBaseOptions depBaseOptions, string appPath)
{
    var deploymentObjectSyncApp = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(
        DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package,
        appPath, new DeploymentBaseOptions());

    deploymentObjectSyncApp.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Auto, string.Empty,
        depBaseOptions, new DeploymentSyncOptions());
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var deployBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions
{
    ComputerName = @"https://WIN-CCCCWWWWXXX:8172/msdeploy.axd",
    UserName = @"WIN-CCCCWWWWXXX\User",
    Password = "123456",
    AuthenticationType = "Basic"
};

// Allow sertification
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, chain, err) => true;

var providerOptions = new DeploymentProviderOptions(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.IisApp)
{
    Path = "MyWebSite"
};

var deploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(providerOptions, deployBaseOptions);
deploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package, "C:\\backup_app.zip", 
               deployBaseOptions, new DeploymentSyncOptions());
```